# Unable to fetch data from a local JSON file, using fetch() in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I'm fetching data in React Native from a JSON file using a fetch statement. This is my App.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {View,Text,ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

const SplashScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style = { styles.container } >
    <ImageBackground  style= { styles.backgroundImage } source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/IGlBYaC.jpg'}} >
            
      <View style= { styles.logoContainer }>
        <Text style = { styles.logoText }>
          Newzzz
        </Text>
        <Text style = { styles.logoDescription }>
          Get your doze of daily news!
        </Text>
        
      </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
} 


const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  console.log("articles: ", props.articles);
  return (
    <View>
      {
        props.articles.map((article, index)=>{
          return <Text key = {index}>
          { article.title }
          </Text>
        })
      }
    </View>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const API_KEY = "API Key here";
  const URL = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=${API_KEY}`;
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("/articles.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      //console.log("I'm in responseJson");
      return responseJson.articles;
    })
    .then( articles  => {
      setArticles(articles);
      //console.log(articles);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.error("The error is:" + error);
    });
    
  } , []);
  
  if (loading){
      return <SplashScreen />
    } else {
      return <HomeScreen articles = { articles }/>
  }
};

export default App
```

Previously I was fetching data from a news API and this code was working fine but now when I am trying to fetch data from a local JSON file. The code is not working anymore. I have checked the console and the code is not logging anything there either. Moreover, there is this error in the console:
[image: error]
This is my first time fetching data from APIs and a JSON file and I can't understand simply what's wrong. I've also checked stack overflow. This is what I've found [image: stackof] Is this a problem with the .json file?
Here's the articles.json file:

```
{
    "articles": [
    {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Brian Heater",
            "title": "Smartphone shipments jumped 27% globally in Q1",
            "description": "More good news from a smartphone market currently rebounding from the far reaching impacts of the pandemic. New numbers from Canalys put global shipments for Q1 2021 at 27% above where they were the same time last year. The industry was hit early and hit hard…",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2021/04/29/smartphone-shipments-jumped-27-globally-in-q1/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/GettyImages-1209693436.jpg?w=667",
            "publishedAt": "2021-04-29T14:07:15Z",
            "content": "More good news from a smartphone market currently rebounding from the far reaching impacts of the pandemic. New numbers from Canalys put global shipments for Q1 2021 at 27% above where they were the … [+1484 chars]"
        },
    {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Brian Heater",
            "title": "Smartphone shipments jumped 27% globally in Q1",
            "description": "More good news from a smartphone market currently rebounding from the far reaching impacts of the pandemic. New numbers from Canalys put global shipments for Q1 2021 at 27% above where they were the same time last year. The industry was hit early and hit hard…",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2021/04/29/smartphone-shipments-jumped-27-globally-in-q1/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/GettyImages-1209693436.jpg?w=667",
            "publishedAt": "2021-04-29T14:07:15Z",
            "content": "More good news from a smartphone market currently rebounding from the far reaching impacts of the pandemic. New numbers from Canalys put global shipments for Q1 2021 at 27% above where they were the … [+1484 chars]"
        }]}
```

I also can't find `data.ok`.Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: Please check the network section in developer console. Maybe `/article.json` file not reachable or it tries to fetch wrong file.

Comment: I've checked the network section. Here's what I can find against articles.json file: ` Name:  articles.json, status: 304, type: fetch`. @delirehberi

Comment: Your JSON is valid. Before calling `response.json()`, check the status code using `response.status`. Make sure it is 200 before you call `response.json()` method.

Comment: it seems not fetch article.json and it uses cached version. maybe this cached version is wrong. can you try to clear browser cache and be sure correct json file come to client.

Comment: Not related to the problem but the `then()` method containing the following statement: `return responseJson.articles;` is unnecessary

Comment: See: [http status 304](https://httpstatuses.com/304)

Comment: The status code was fine @Yousaf

Comment: I've tried running it on different browsers. This isn't working on either so I don't think there's some problem with the cache. @delirehberi

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Placed the code of the JSON file on GitHub, in the JSON file, clicked on **RAW**  and then copied the **URL**. Fetched the JSON data from the URL and it worked.